# Boost asio C++ 20 Coroutines: co_spawn a coroutine with a by-reference parameter unexpected result

Tags: c++, boost-asio, c++20, c++-coroutine

In the following code, the parameter of the session coroutine is passed by reference.

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>

boost::asio::awaitable<void> session(const std::string& name)
{
    std::cout << "Starting " << name << std::endl;
    auto executor = co_await boost::asio::this_coro::executor;
}

int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_context io_context;

    co_spawn(io_context, session("ServerA"), boost::asio::detached);
    co_spawn(io_context, session("ServerB"), boost::asio::detached);

    io_context.run();

    return 0;
}
```

For some reason that I don't understand, the above code results in printing **Starting ServerB** twice.

```
> g++ -std=c++20 ../test-coro.cpp -o test-coro && ./test-coro
Starting ServerB
Starting ServerB
```

But when I change the coroutine parameter to pass by value, it will correctly print both **Starting ServerA** and **Starting ServerB**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>

boost::asio::awaitable<void> session(std::string name)
{
    std::cout << "Starting " << name << std::endl;
    auto executor = co_await boost::asio::this_coro::executor;
}

int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_context io_context;

    co_spawn(io_context, session("ServerA"), boost::asio::detached);
    co_spawn(io_context, session("ServerB"), boost::asio::detached);

    io_context.run();

    return 0;
}
```

```
> g++ -std=c++20 ../test-coro.cpp -o test-coro && ./test-coro
Starting ServerA
Starting ServerB
```

Is it expected or this is a compiler/library bug? If it is expected, then what's the reasoning for it?

Environment:
Arch Linux 5.18.16-arch1-1
gcc (GCC) 12.2.0
boost version 1.79

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can think of the coroutine state as containing what would be on the function call stack (which is what makes the function resumable): [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/coroutines#:%7E:text=When%20a%20coroutine%20begins%20execution%2C%20it%20performs%20the%20following)

> When a coroutine begins execution, it performs the following:
>
> - allocates the coroutine state object using operator new (see below)
> - copies all function parameters to the coroutine state: by-value parameters are moved or copied, by-reference parameters remain
>   references (and so may become dangling if the coroutine is resumed
>   after the lifetime of referred object ends)

The coroutine logically stores a reference to a temporary string. Oops.

I haven't checked, but I'd assume that Asio's awaitable implementation starts with an initial `suspend_always` (this makes intuitive sense to me with respect to the executor model).

Yes, this means that `co_spawn` with any reference argument means the lifetime of the object referenced must be guaranteed.

On my system, the output was merely

```
Starting
Starting
```

One fix is what you showed. To illustrate out the lifetime aspect:

```
{
    std::string a="ServerA", b="ServerB";
    co_spawn(io_context, session(a), boost::asio::detached);
    co_spawn(io_context, session(b), boost::asio::detached);

    io_context.run();
}
```

Is also a valid fix. For the trivial example I'd suggest a `std::string_view` regardless:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ee42f74d6c8a8cc8)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

boost::asio::awaitable<void> session(std::string_view name)
{
    std::cout << "Starting " << std::quoted(name) << std::endl;
    auto executor = co_await boost::asio::this_coro::executor;
}

int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_context io_context;

    std::string const a="ServerA";
    co_spawn(io_context, session(a), boost::asio::detached);
    co_spawn(io_context, session("ServerB"), boost::asio::detached);

    io_context.run();
}
```

Printing

```
Starting "ServerA"
Starting "ServerB"
```

Comment: "Oops" for sure. It makes sense now. Thanks

Comment: I'm going to stick with std::string by-value parameter. I want to avoid the potential situation when the function user, uses the function with temporaries, for example, using string_literals operators and etc. It seems, generally, it's a good practice to make sure values are being copied or moved into coroutines. What are your thoughts?

Comment: I'd agree. I just wanted to make sure you understood the options so you can choose