# Boost asio steady_timer work on different strand than intended

Tags: c++, boost-asio, c++20, c++-coroutine

I am trying to use asio :: steady_timer in asio coroutine (using asio :: awaitable). steady_timer
should work on a different strand (executor1) than spawned coroutine strand (executor), but asio handler tracking support shows that otherwise I clearly give the timer its strand it working on asio Coroutine strand, any thoughts why?

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>

#define ASIO_ENABLE_HANDLER_TRACKING
#include <asio.hpp>

#define HANDLER_LOCATION BOOST_ASIO_HANDLER_LOCATION((__FILE__, __LINE__, __func__))

asio::awaitable<void> start(asio::strand<asio::io_context::executor_type>& ex)
{
    asio::steady_timer timer{ex};

    timer.expires_after(std::chrono::milliseconds{500});
    auto timer_awaitable = std::optional<asio::awaitable<void>>();
    {
        ASIO_HANDLER_LOCATION((__FILE__, __LINE__, "my_connection_impl::connect_and_send" ));
        //timer_awaitable.emplace(timer.async_wait(asio::bind_executor(ex, asio::use_awaitable)));  
        timer_awaitable.emplace(timer.async_wait(asio::use_awaitable));               
    }
    co_await std::move(*timer_awaitable);
    std::cerr<<"timer async_wait \n";

    co_return;
}

int main()
{
    asio::io_context io_context;
    asio::strand<asio::io_context::executor_type> executor{io_context.get_executor()};
    asio::strand<asio::io_context::executor_type> executor1{io_context.get_executor()};

    asio::co_spawn(executor, start(executor1), asio::detached);

    io_context.run();
    std::cerr<<"end \n";

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
@asio|1661509595.252484|0^1|in 'co_spawn_entry_point' (.../asio_test/build/_deps/boostasio-src/asio:153)
@asio|1661509595.252484|0*1|strand_executor@0x561f97dcd6c0.execute
@asio|1661509595.252657|0^2|in 'co_spawn_entry_point' (.../asio_test/build/_deps/boostasio-src/asio:153)
@asio|1661509595.252657|0*2|io_context@0x7ffe388194a0.execute
@asio|1661509595.252684|>2|
@asio|1661509595.252691|>1|
@asio|1661509595.252779|1*3|deadline_timer@0x561f97dcd850.async_wait
@asio|1661509595.252825|<1|
@asio|1661509595.252835|<2|
@asio|1661509595.753514|>3|ec=system:0
@asio|1661509595.753577|3*4|strand_executor@0x561f97dcd6c0.execute
@asio|1661509595.753589|>4|
timer async_wait 
@asio|1661509595.753698|4|deadline_timer@0x561f97dcd850.cancel
@asio|1661509595.753723|<4|
@asio|1661509595.753731|<3|
end
```

One way to fix that is to use:
`timer_awaitable.emplace(timer.async_wait(asio::bind_executor(ex, asio::use_awaitable)));`
instead of:
`timer_awaitable.emplace(timer.async_wait(asio::use_awaitable));`

But is this mean that when co_await resumes this coroutine from now it will work on different strand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass the executor by reference. This is atypical. Executors are light-weight and cheaply copyable.

In your case this happens to be ok, because the lifetime of `executor1` exceeds the coroutine, and it isn't being modified on another thread, but in general, avoid reference arguments to coros (see e.g [Boost asio C++ 20 Coroutines: co_spawn a coroutine with a by-reference parameter unexpected result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73471450/boost-asio-c-20-coroutines-co-spawn-a-coroutine-with-a-by-reference-parameter/73471786#73471786)).

Other than it seems to be only a matter of expectations.

The executor that is bound into an IO object (in your case, `timer`) is used *by default*(!) for *unbound* completion handlers. This is e.g.:

```
asio::steady_timer timer {ex};
timer.async_await([](error_code) { });
```

Here the completion handler is unbound, and will default to the executor you expect (`ex`). Handlers can have associated executors in a number of ways, e.g. the explicit:

```
asio::steady_timer timer {ex};
timer.async_await(asio::bind_executor(my_ex, [](error_code) { });
```

Here the completion will always happen on `my_ex` regardless of the timer's executor.

In the case of coroutines, the executor associated with the completion token is implicitly `co_await asio::this_coro::executor`. If you want to forcibly resume the current coro on a different executor, the cleanest way would be to `co_spawn` to it.

You can *also* override the executor manually, like I show in this answer: [asio How to change the executor inside an awaitable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71987021/asio-how-to-change-the-executor-inside-an-awaitable/71991876#71991876):

```
    timer_awaitable = timer.async_wait(bind_executor(ex, asio::use_awaitable));
```

> But is this mean that when co_await resumes this coroutine from now it will work on different strand?

Yes.

Comment: I appreciate your answer!.

(0) Executors are itself like some kind of "reference" to io_context, right? but is the same thing with strand-s?. 

(1) Could You show some simple smple code how to co_spawn coro on a different executor? I cannot immage how to do this. 

(2) So `asio::use_awaitable` has implicitly associated asio::this_coro::executor executor?! is that mean it has also implicitly associated cancellation_slot from coroutine?.

Comment: Yes, executors hold a reference to the execution context. Strands are executors. An examples of `co_await co_spawn` was [hidden in the comments here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71987021/asio-how-to-change-the-executor-inside-an-awaitable/71991876#comment127347929_71991876). About cancellation slots I'm less knowledgeable, but it would seems so: [_Supported [....] C++20 coroutines that `use awaitable`_](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/cancellation.html#:~:text=coroutines%20that%20use%20awaitable)**