# Can I co_await an operation executed by one io_context in a coroutine executed by another in Asio?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, c++20, asio

I have an HTTP server library writen by Asio with `one io_context per thread` model. It has an `io_context_pool` which retrieves one `io_context` orderly. So when the server starts, `io_context #1` will be used to execute the acceptor and `io_context #2` will be used for the first connection and `io_context #3` will be with the second and so on.

It also wait for signal to call the `io_context.stop()` orderly to stop the server and it works well.

I would like to refactor it with C++20 coroutine. I've almost finished but I found that if signal reveived to call `io_context.stop()`, `heap used after free` will be reported by sanitizer. I've no idea how to solve this.

Here is a simplified example:

```cpp
constexpr int wait_second = 2;
constexpr int run_second = 3;

asio::awaitable<void> co_main(asio::io_context& other_ctx){
    asio::steady_timer timer(other_ctx);
    timer.expires_after(std::chrono::seconds(wait_second));
    co_await timer.async_wait(asio::use_awaitable);
    std::cout<<"timer"<<std::endl;
}

int main() {
    asio::io_context ctx;
    asio::io_context other_ctx;
    asio::executor_work_guard<asio::io_context::executor_type> g1(ctx.get_executor());
    asio::executor_work_guard<asio::io_context::executor_type> g2(other_ctx.get_executor());

    asio::co_spawn(ctx, co_main(other_ctx), asio::detached);

    std::thread([&]{
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(run_second));
        ctx.stop();
        other_ctx.stop();
    }).detach();
    std::thread t1([&]{ctx.run();});
    std::thread t2([&]{other_ctx.run();});
    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    return 0;
}
```

The coroutine `co_main` is executed by `ctx` but the timer in it is executed by `other_ctx`. The `wait_second` represents the waiting duration of the timer while `run_second` represent after how many seconds the `ctx` and `io_context` will be stopped.

If the `wait_second` is less than `run_second`, everything works fine but if `wait_second` is longer, `heap used after free` will be reported by sanitizer. So is this the right way to use `asio::awaitable`? Can I mix use the `io_context` with coroutine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this usage is fine. Not optimal, but fine.

The thing to note about binding IO objects to an executor is that it mostly serves two purposes:

1. firstly it indicates which execution context holds the service instance for the IO object's implementation
2. secondly it serves as the *default*(!) executor for completion handlers

Note that 1. implies that it may incur more overhead than sharing the context, and 2. means that there is little behavioral difference in this case. It's the default only, so the awaitable's coro executor overrides it here. This may not be as you expected. See e.g. this similar question [Boost asio steady_timer work on different strand than intended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73499804/boost-asio-steady-timer-work-on-different-strand-than-intended/73500041#73500041)

### What's the sanitizer issue

It's a lifetime issue. Let's instrument a bit and use `BOOST_ASIO_ENABLE_HANDLER_TRACKING` as well:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
namespace asio = boost::asio;

constexpr auto wait_for = 200ms, run_for = 300ms;

asio::awaitable<void> co_main(asio::io_context& other_ctx){
    asio::steady_timer timer{other_ctx.get_executor(), wait_for};
    co_await timer.async_wait(asio::use_awaitable);
    std::cout << "timer" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    {
        asio::io_context other_ctx;
        {
            asio::io_context ctx;
            //auto g1 = ctx.get_executor();
            //auto g2 = other_ctx.get_executor();

            asio::co_spawn(ctx, co_main(other_ctx), asio::detached);

            std::thread stopper([&] {
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(run_for);
                ctx.stop();
                other_ctx.stop();
            });

            std::thread t1([&] { ctx.run(); });
            std::thread t2([&] { other_ctx.run(); });
            stopper.join();
            t1.join();
            t2.join();
            std::cout << "All joined" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "ctx:       " << &ctx       << std::endl;
            std::cout << "other_ctx: " << &other_ctx << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << "ctx destructed" << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "other_ctx destructed" << std::endl;
}
```

After all threads are done (and joined), the destructor of `other_ctx` abandons all operations in the operation queue. Some of the completions are bound to the executor of `ctx` (because of the coro, see above) which is already gone. This leads to the use-after-scope (truncating for SO):

```
@asio|1661689229.839262|0^1|in 'co_spawn_entry_point' (/home/sehe/custom/superboost/boost/asio/impl/co_spawn.hpp:154)
@asio|1661689229.839262|0*1|io_context@0x7ffe27cf56a0.execute
@asio|1661689229.839715|>1|
@asio|1661689229.839961|1*2|deadline_timer@0x6110000000a0.async_wait
@asio|1661689229.839986|<1|
All joined
ctx:       0x7ffe27cf56a0
other_ctx: 0x7ffe27cf5680
ctx destructed
@asio|1661689230.139986|2*3|io_context@0x7ffe27cf56a0.execute
=================================================================
==16129==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-use-after-scope on address 0x7ffe27cf56a8 at pc 0x55bace9962f6 bp 0x7ffe27cf4270 sp 0x7ffe27cf4260
READ of size 8 at 0x7ffe27cf56a8 thread T0
    #0 0x55bace9962f5 in void boost::asio::io_context::basic_executor_type<std::allocator<void>, 0ul>::....hpp:319
    #1 0x55bace968067 in void boost::asio::execution::detail::any_executor_base::execute<boost::asio::d....hpp:611
    #2 0x55bace968067 in std::enable_if<boost_asio_execution_execute_fn::call_traits<boost_asio_executi....hpp:208
    #3 0x55bace968067 in void boost::asio::detail::initiate_post_with_executor<boost::asio::any_io_exec....hpp:122
    #4 0x55bace968067 in void boost::asio::detail::completion_handler_async_result<boost::asio::detail:....hpp:482
    #5 0x55bace968067 in boost::asio::constraint<boost::asio::detail::async_result_has_initiate_memfn<b....hpp:896
    #6 0x55bace968067 in auto boost::asio::post<boost::asio::any_io_executor, boost::asio::detail::awai....hpp:242
    #7 0x55bace969443 in boost::asio::detail::awaitable_thread<boost::asio::any_io_executor>::~awaitabl....hpp:673
    #8 0x55bace99ecb0 in boost::asio::detail::awaitable_handler_base<boost::asio::any_io_executor, void....hpp:29
    #9 0x55bace99ecb0 in boost::asio::detail::awaitable_handler<boost::asio::any_io_executor, boost::sy....hpp:78
    #10 0x55bace99ecb0 in boost::asio::detail::binder1<boost::asio::detail::awaitable_handler<boost::as....hpp:139
    #11 0x55bace99ecb0 in boost::asio::detail::wait_handler<boost::asio::detail::awaitable_handler<boos....hpp:67
    #12 0x55bace91be12 in boost::asio::detail::scheduler_operation::destroy() /home/sehe/custom/superbo....hpp:45
    #13 0x55bace91be12 in void boost::asio::detail::op_queue_access::destroy<boost::asio::detail::sched....hpp:47
    #14 0x55bace91be12 in boost::asio::detail::op_queue<boost::asio::detail::scheduler_operation>::~op_....hpp:81
    #15 0x55bace91be12 in boost::asio::detail::scheduler::abandon_operations(boost::asio::detail::op_qu....ipp:444
    #16 0x55bace91be12 in boost::asio::detail::epoll_reactor::shutdown() /home/sehe/custom/superboost/b....ipp:92
    #17 0x55bace8ebc8c in boost::asio::detail::service_registry::shutdown_services() /home/sehe/custom/....ipp:44
    #18 0x55bace8ebc8c in boost::asio::execution_context::shutdown() /home/sehe/custom/superboost/boost....ipp:41
    #19 0x55bace8ebc8c in boost::asio::execution_context::~execution_context() /home/sehe/custom/superb....ipp:34
    #20 0x55bace88d684 in boost::asio::io_context::~io_context() /home/sehe/custom/superboost/boost/asi....ipp:56
    #21 0x55bace88d684 in main /home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp:16
    #22 0x7efe676d0c86 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x21c86)
    #23 0x55bace88e859 in _start (/home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/build/sotest+0x1a5859)

Address 0x7ffe27cf56a8 is located in stack of thread T0 at offset 904 in frame
    #0 0x55bace88bd2f in main /home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp:14

  This frame has 34 object(s):
    // ... skipped
    [128, 136) '<unknown>'
    [160, 168) 'stopper' (line 24)
    [192, 200) 't1' (line 30)
    [224, 232) '<unknown>'
    [256, 264) 't2' (line 31)
    [288, 296) '<unknown>'
    // ... skipped
    [832, 840) '<unknown>'
    [864, 880) 'other_ctx' (line 16)
    [896, 912) 'ctx' (line 18) <== Memory access at offset 904 is inside this variable
    [928, 944) '<unknown>'
    [960, 1016) '<unknown>'
    [1056, 1112) '<unknown>'
HINT: this may be a false positive if your program uses some custom stack unwind mechanism, swapcontext or vfork
      (longjmp and C++ exceptions *are* supported)
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: stack-use-after-scope /home/sehe/custom/superboost/boost/asio/impl/io_context.hpp:319 in void boost::asio::io_context::basic_executor_type<std::allocator<void>, 0ul>::execute<boost::asio::detail::executor_function>(boost::asio::detail::executor_function&&) const
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x100044f96a80: f8 f2 f2 f2 f8 f2 f2 f2 f8 f2 f2 f2 f8 f2 f2 f2
  0x100044f96a90: f8 f2 f2 f2 f8 f2 f2 f2 00 f2 f2 f2 00 f2 f2 f2
  0x100044f96aa0: 00 f2 f2 f2 f8 f2 f2 f2 f8 f2 f2 f2 f8 f2 f2 f2
  0x100044f96ab0: f8 f2 f2 f2 f8 f2 f2 f2 f8 f2 f2 f2 f8 f2 f2 f2
  0x100044f96ac0: f8 f2 f2 f2 f8 f2 f2 f2 f8 f2 f2 f2 f8 f2 f2 f2
=>0x100044f96ad0: 00 00 f2 f2 f8[f8]f2 f2 f8 f8 f2 f2 f8 f8 f8 f8
  0x100044f96ae0: f8 f8 f8 f2 f2 f2 f2 f2 f8 f8 f8 f8 f8 f8 f8 f3
  0x100044f96af0: f3 f3 f3 f3 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x100044f96b00: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x100044f96b10: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x100044f96b20: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
  Heap left redzone:       fa
  Freed heap region:       fd
  Stack left redzone:      f1
  Stack mid redzone:       f2
  Stack right redzone:     f3
  Stack after return:      f5
  Stack use after scope:   f8
  Global redzone:          f9
  Global init order:       f6
  Poisoned by user:        f7
  Container overflow:      fc
  Array cookie:            ac
  Intra object redzone:    bb
  ASan internal:           fe
  Left alloca redzone:     ca
  Right alloca redzone:    cb
  Shadow gap:              cc
==16129==ABORTING
```

Ironically, flipping the order of executor destruction doesn't help:

```
{
    asio::io_context ctx;
    {
        asio::io_context other_ctx;
        // ... skiped unchanged
    }
    std::cout << "other_ctx destructed" << std::endl;
}
std::cout << "ctx destructed" << std::endl;
```

Now we get the inverse dependency: after all threads have joined, the destructor of `other_ctx` correctly queues completion for the `async_wait` on  `ctx`. But once `ctx` destructor shuts down its services, it will destroy the coro stack frame, which includes the timer object which ... has a stale reference to the `other_ctx` destructor.

```
@asio|1661689960.225134|0^1|in 'co_spawn_entry_point' (/home/sehe/custom/superboost/boost/asio/impl/co_spawn.hpp:154)
@asio|1661689960.225134|0*1|io_context@0x7ffd9e839d80.execute
@asio|1661689960.225576|>1|
@asio|1661689960.225876|1*2|deadline_timer@0x6110000000a0.async_wait
@asio|1661689960.225899|<1|
All joined
ctx:       0x7ffd9e839d80
other_ctx: 0x7ffd9e839da0
@asio|1661689960.525759|2*3|io_context@0x7ffd9e839d80.execute
@asio|1661689960.525773|~2|
other_ctx destructed
/usr/include/c++/10/coroutine:128: runtime error: member call on null pointer of type 'struct steady_timer'
/home/sehe/custom/superboost/boost/asio/basic_waitable_timer.hpp:382:3: runtime error: member access within null pointer of type 'struct basic_waitable_timer'
/home/sehe/custom/superboost/boost/asio/basic_waitable_timer.hpp:382:3: runtime error: member call on null pointer of type 'struct io_object_impl'
/home/sehe/custom/superboost/boost/asio/detail/io_object_impl.hpp:97:5: runtime error: member access within null pointer of type 'struct io_object_impl'
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
=================================================================
==22649==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x000000000000 (pc 0x558135f6b18f bp 0x7ffd9e837d10 sp 0x7ffd9e837a00 T0)
==22649==The signal is caused by a READ memory access.
==22649==Hint: address points to the zero page.
    #0 0x558135f6b18f in boost::asio::detail::io_object_impl<boost::asio::detail::deadline_timer_service<bo....hpp:97
    #1 0x558135e6d07a in boost::asio::basic_waitable_timer<std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock, boost::asio::wai....hpp:382
    #2 0x558135e6d07a in co_main(boost::asio::io_context&) [clone .actor] /home/sehe/custom/superboost/boos....hpp:380
    #3 0x558135f0b5e9 in std::__n4861::coroutine_handle<void>::destroy() const /usr/include/c++/10/coroutine:128
    #4 0x558135f0b5e9 in boost::asio::detail::awaitable_frame_base<boost::asio::any_io_executor>::destroy()....hpp:496
    #5 0x558135f0b5e9 in boost::asio::awaitable<void, boost::asio::any_io_executor>::~awaitable() /home/seh....hpp:77
    #6 0x558135f0b5e9 in boost::asio::awaitable<boost::asio::detail::awaitable_thread_entry_point, boost::a....actor] /home/sehe/custom/superboost/boost/asio/impl/co_spawn.hpp:183
    #7 0x558135ea6d1d in std::__n4861::coroutine_handle<void>::destroy() const /usr/include/c++/10/coroutine:128
    #8 0x558135ea6d1d in boost::asio::detail::awaitable_frame_base<boost::asio::any_io_executor>::destroy()....hpp:496
    #9 0x558135ea6d1d in boost::asio::awaitable<boost::asio::detail::awaitable_thread_entry_point, boost::a....hpp:77
    #10 0x558135ea6d1d in boost::asio::detail::awaitable_thread<boost::asio::any_io_executor>::~awaitable_t....hpp:674
    #11 0x558135ea6d1d in boost::asio::detail::binder0<boost::asio::detail::awaitable_thread<boost::asio::a....hpp:32
    #12 0x558135ea6d1d in void boost::asio::detail::executor_function::complete<boost::asio::detail::binder....hpp:110
    #13 0x558135f6ecfb in boost::asio::detail::executor_function::~executor_function() /home/sehe/custom/su....hpp:55
    #14 0x558135f6ecfb in boost::asio::detail::executor_op<boost::asio::detail::executor_function, std::all....hpp:62
    #15 0x558135ec4893 in boost::asio::detail::scheduler_operation::destroy() /home/sehe/custom/superboost/....hpp:45
    #16 0x558135ec4893 in boost::asio::detail::scheduler::shutdown() /home/sehe/custom/superboost/boost/asi....ipp:176
    #17 0x558135ebfc8c in boost::asio::detail::service_registry::shutdown_services() /home/sehe/custom/supe....ipp:44
    #18 0x558135ebfc8c in boost::asio::execution_context::shutdown() /home/sehe/custom/superboost/boost/asi....ipp:41
    #19 0x558135ebfc8c in boost::asio::execution_context::~execution_context() /home/sehe/custom/superboost....ipp:34
    #20 0x558135e61684 in boost::asio::io_context::~io_context() /home/sehe/custom/superboost/boost/asio/im....ipp:56
    #21 0x558135e61684 in main /home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp:16
    #22 0x7fbd0bd07c86 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x21c86)
    #23 0x558135e62859 in _start (/home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/build/sotest+0x1a5859)

AddressSanitizer can not provide additional info.
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: SEGV /home/sehe/custom/superboost/boost/asio/detail/io_object_impl.hpp:97 in boost::asio::detail::io_object_impl<boost::asio::detail::deadline_timer_service<boost::asio::detail::chrono_time_traits<std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock, boost::asio::wait_traits<std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock> > >, boost::asio::any_io_executor>::~io_object_impl()
==22649==ABORTING
```

The problem appears to be that the coro frame outlives the lifetime of `other_ctx` here.

### Conclusion

You have to avoid destruction of both contexts from inter-depending cyclically. This practically means avoiding uncompleted operations in their operation queues.

It's good to note that the problems mostly start with using `io_context::stop()` to stop context mid-operation. In addition, there doesn't currently seem to be a reason `run()` the `other_ctx` in the first place.

Consider using async completion / awaitable operators with cancellation.

Comment: I ran out of time to get to the bottom of things and writing up a good, idiomatic counter-example. I kept seeing unexpected lifetime issues. I'm suspecting there's something going on under the hood with the new cancellation slots that I'm not fully aware of, so I was watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=icgnqFM-aY4) and [the next](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hHk5OXlKVFg).

Comment: Thanks for your answer and it totally solves my confuse. As the recommandation, I have to ensure that all the operations should be completed before context is stopped. It might be a way. But do you think using `one io_context in all threads` should be a better way to avoid such cyclical issue? I found that `io_context per thread` has much better performance so that's the reason why I chose this at the beginning.

Comment: Another possible way I can come up is ensure that all the operation attached to the same executor in the same coroutine. And use callback to dispatch the executor and start a coroutine. Do you think it's doable?

Comment: How did you find that having an `io_context` per thread improves performance? It seems a bit unlikely (although with [the right build config and concurrency hints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73505015/boost-asio-experimental-channel-poor-performance/73507006#73507006) or specific work loads I can see it happen).

Comment: I don't see exactly what you mean with the callback. If that's an option, then I imagineyou can `co_await co_spawn(other_ex, foo)`?

Comment: Actually it's not performance but concurrency. I just wrote a pretty raw and simple HTTP server, it accepted the request and always returned the same string. With `io_context` per thread (I use six threads), I found the req/sec is 10%-15% more than that with one `io_context` accross all threads. I've also tried adding BOOST_ASIO_CONCURRENCY_HINT_UNSAFE to `io_context` but the result is the same.

Comment: The callback means the completion token for async operation. I've made the acceptor accept the request and then start a coroutine with `co_spawn` in the completion token. With this structure, I can assign the different connection with different `io_context` in the context pool orderly and keep the operation in the same coroutine work with the same executor. It works well now.